# Storing HTML GeoLocations to PHP variables

Tags: php, javascript, html, geolocation

I am currently trying to get the geolocation through html5 and storing them into a php variable for further processing.

I have followed the example [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp), but I can't figure out how I can change the function to return the latitude and longitude and store them in seperate php variales $lat and $lon.

Here is my code (Its incorrect). Its a php function that prints out the scripts for geolocation.

```
function printGeoLocScript() {
    echo <<<_END

    <script>
function getLatitude()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLat,showError);
    }
  else{return  "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }

function getLongitude()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLon,showError);
    }
  else{return  "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function getLat(position)
  {
  return  position.coords.latitude;
  }

function getLon(position)
  {
   return position.coords.longitude;    
  }

function showError(error)
  {
  switch(error.code) 
    {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      return "User denied the request for Geolocation."
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      return "Location information is unavailable."
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      return "The request to get user location timed out."
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
     return "An unknown error occurred."

    }
  }
</script>

_END;
}
```

Note that if the coordinates are not available, I want both functions (getLongitude and getLatitude to return the string error via the showError method.

Finally, these methods would be called via a post action of a form.. (I shouldnt have any problems there though)

Comment: Client-side Javascript and server-side PHP are two entirely different things. See [Send JavaScript variable to PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342486/send-javascript-variable-to-php) and a host of other similar questions. Learn AJAX.

Comment: Isn't it possible to get the coordinates through a form like you do for textfields etc..(by using post?)

Comment: Well, yes, you can essentially create a form, filling in the values and submit it, all via Javascript. This will reload the page though; typically you want to do that more unobtrusively in the background through AJAX.

Comment: I dont mind reloading the page... I wish to know from where the user comes from when creating an account. Once he fills in his account details, the geo function that I require will be called and the coordinates will be sent along with his details.

Comment: This issue has been solved. I will post my answer later today.